# Member function syntax in class template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, template-specialization

I have a class template, let's call it `A`, which has a member function `abc()`:

```
template <typename T>
class A{
public:
    T value;
    void abc();
};
```

I can implement the member function `abc()` outside the class declaration, using the following syntax:

```
template <typename T>
void A<T>::abc()
{
    value++;
}
```

What I want to do is to create a template specialization for this class, let's say `int`.

```
template <>
class A<int>{
public:
    int value;
    void abc();
};
```

**The question is:** what is the correct syntax to implement `abc()` for the specialized class?

I tried using the following syntax:

```
template <>
void A<int>::abc()
{
   value += 2;
}
```

However this doesn't compile.

Comment: Incidentally, your syntax would have worked if you hadn't specialized the entire class template, too. You *can* specialize individual member functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void A<int>::abc()
{
   value += 2;
}
```

since `A<int>` is `explicit specialisation` of `A<T>`.

http://liveworkspace.org/code/982c66b2cbfdb56305180914266831d1

n3337 14.7.3/5

> **Members of an explicitly specialized class template are
> defined in the same manner as members of normal classes, and not using the template<> syntax**.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct A {
> struct B { };
> template<class U> struct C { };
> };
> template<> struct A<int> {
> void f(int);
> };
> void h() {
> A<int> a;
> a.f(16);
> }
> // A<int>::f must be defined somewhere
> // template<> not used for a member of an
> // explicitly specialized class template
> void A<int>::f(int) { /∗ ... ∗/ }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `template<>`:

```
void A<int>::abc()
{
   value += 2;
}
```